# 2 x 2 matrix with matrix elements $a_{ij}=i-j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm just starting to study linear algebra [self teaching]. I came across this reference online and I'm not sure what it's referring to: **Identify the two-by-two matrix with matrix elements $a_{ij}=i-j$:**

I know a diagonal 3x3 matrix such that $a_{ij} = i = j$ might be written like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

But unsure what it means with  $a_{ij}=i-j$:

​

Comment: $a_{12}=1-2$,$ a_{21}=2-1$, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is exactly like it seems. If you have an entry $a_{i,j}$ then the value at that entry is just $ i - j$.

so here we have our 2x2 matrix A

\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}

then $a_{1,2}$ is just 1-2=-1 and so on for each entry.
we get the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}